# Python mistype prevention

Tags: python

I often mistype names of variables in python, and python is dynamic, so i detect it only when incorrect code runs.
How can i prevent mistyping in python?

Answer (score 2):

Use an editor: Eclipse + PyDev has a good detection system for these kinds of errors.
Also tools as [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) can help

Comment: It's pretty helpless against typos in attribute/method names though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set highlight words in most good editors like vim and emacs.

Vim: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words
Emacs: http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/

Answer (score 0):

Try pyflakes. It can find many errors in Python programs, including mistyped variables.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running all your files through various static code checkers.

Here is a list of those I use for everyday programming:

- [`flake8`](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) (`pip install flake8`) and [`flake8-bugbear`](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-bugbear/) (`pip install flake8-bugbear`)
- [`pylint`](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) (`pip install pylint`)
- [`black`](https://pypi.org/project/black/) (`pip install black`)

Some people also like:

- [`pylama`](https://github.com/klen/pylama)

These tools will check style and find syntax errors like misspelled variable names.

Some of them are quite opinionated when it comes to style (e.g. `black`) but can be configured to ignore certain style mismatches.